# MariaDB 10.4 Query Optimizer Wrong Execution Plan

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, execution-plan, cardinality-estimates

I have a very strange behavior with some tables and the query optimizer on a MariaDB server.

First of all we have our main table let's call it huge and we have on the same database another table a clone of him with limited range rows.

HUGE table has a range

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
| min(dispatch_time) | max(dispatch_time) |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| 20070402114058     | 20201207000108     |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

with count rows

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 46683586 |
+----------+
```

and CLONE one has a range

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
| min(dispatch_time) | max(dispatch_time) |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| 20190101143607     | 20201207000108     |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

with count rows

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 10346027 |
+----------+
```

They have the same indexes

HUGE one

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table1 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | order_id      | A         |    44735742 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table1 |          1 | Index_Customer |            1 | customer_id   | A         |    11183935 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table1 |          1 | Index_3        |            1 | dispatch_time | A         |    44735742 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

CLONE smaller one

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table1 |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | order_id      | A         |    10346027 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table1 |          1 | Index_Customer |            1 | customer_id   | A         |     2041159 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table1 |          1 | Index_3        |            1 | dispatch_time | A         |     8070853 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Now the problem is with this simple specific query.

On the HUGE one table if we run this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM   `table1` WHERE
     ( `dispatch_time` BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190601' );
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table1    | range | Index_3       | Index_3 | 15      | NULL | 5201896 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+


SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM   `table1` WHERE
     ( `dispatch_time` BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190601' );
1695926 rows in set (21.730 sec)
```

So far so good. It uses a type range, using index condition, the result rows time is acceptable everything is fine.

BUT on the smaller one look what happens with the same query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM   `table1` WHERE
     ( `dispatch_time` BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190601' );
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table1    | ALL  | Index_3       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10346027 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM   `table1` WHERE
     ( `dispatch_time` BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190601' );
1695926 rows in set (39.470 sec)
```

It does a full table scan, the type is ALL and is not using the Index.

The query optimizer does not choose the index because of the cost as i have did an optimizer_trace and this is the problematic part.

On the HUGE table it goes

```
{\
                        "index": "Index_3",\
                        "ranges": ["(20190201) <= (dispatch_time) <= (20190601)"],\
                        "rowid_ordered": false,\
                        "using_mrr": false,\
                        "index_only": false,\
                        "rows": 5201896,\
                        "cost": 6.51e6,\
                        "chosen": true\
}
```

on the CLONE smaller one

```
{\
                        "index": "Index_3",\
                        "ranges": ["(20190201) <= (dispatch_time) <= (20190601)"],\
                        "rowid_ordered": false,\
                        "using_mrr": false,\
                        "index_only": false,\
                        "rows": 3375750,\
                        "cost": 4.23e6,\
                        "chosen": false,\
                        "cause": "cost"\
}
```

I come to the conclusion that the cardinality of the CLONE table does not make the query optimizer to use the Index but the thing is Why?

Why to execute and go this way and do a full table scan on a smaller table although the index is there? How to tell the optimizer to change the plan? If you use force index, it uses the index and the result rows time is similar to HUGE table.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM   `table1` FORCE INDEX (Index_3) WHERE ( `dispatch_time` BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190601' );
```

I have done multiple analyze table persistent for all on this table nothing changed. Tried various tweaks etc but always the execution plan does not use the Index condition on the small CLONE table.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

Edit post for:

SHOW CREATE TABLE

HUGE ONE

```
table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `table_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codename` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dispatch_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buffet_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receipt_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `return_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expected_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completion_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `promotion` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `takeaway` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `esan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destroy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `returned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `discountS` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `policy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packing` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `production` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vitrine` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sch_start` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sch_finish` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preorder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  KEY `Index_Customer` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `Index_3` (`dispatch_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46739244 DEFAULT CHARSET=greek COMMENT='InnoDB free: 12288 kB'
```

CLONE ONE

```
table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `table_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codename` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dispatch_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buffet_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receipt_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `return_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expected_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completion_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `promotion` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `takeaway` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `esan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destroy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `returned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `discountS` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `policy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packing` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `production` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vitrine` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sch_start` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sch_finish` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_time` char(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preorder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  KEY `Index_Customer` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `Index_3` (`dispatch_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46739244 DEFAULT CHARSET=greek COMMENT='InnoDB free: 12288 kB'
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I am pretty sure the datatype for `dispatch_time` is messed up.  Do you get the correct results?

Comment: I edited the post to check the SHOW CREATE TABLE. Thank you.

Comment: How much RAM; what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Did you 'time' each query twice?  (The first may be doing more I/O than subsequent runs.)

Comment: I did time them multiple times. The ```innodb_buffer_pool_size``` is ```innodb_buffer_pool_size | 51539607552```

Comment: What does the client do with a resultset of 1.7M rows?  If we can cut that back drastically, it would help the system performance and make the Question go away.

Comment: Assuming you have 64GB of RAM, it sounds like that table will easily fit in the buffer_pool and stay there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as you mentioned due to the `cardinality` difference between the two tables. It sounds like you understand what `cardinality` is on the surface, but to answer your question "why?" let me provide a little more information first.

So in short, `cardinality` is a measurement of uniqueness for a given value in a `Table`, in other words it measures the number of occurrences of a value relative to the total values in that `Table`. The SQL engine stores `statistics` about the `cardinalities` of every value in your `Tables` so it can make a decision on the most efficient way to serve that data later on when queried.

When you write a query, the `predicates` (values of the conditions in your `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses) are used to filter the data of the `Table` based on those values. So the SQL engine uses its `statistics` for those particular values from your `predicates` to decide what kind of `Execution Plan` would be most performant, for example something with a low `cardinality` (low uniqueness, so high number of records contain that value) a `full scan` makes sense as opposed to an `index seek` (on a B-Tree) which would occur for a value with high `cardinality` (high uniqueness, not a lot of rows contain that value).

That being said, the direct answer to your question "why?" is because an `index seek` operation on a large amount of values (relatively speaking) is generally significantly slower of an operation as opposed to a `full scan`. Though the engine isn't exactly perfect and then this is why [`index hints`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index-hints-how-to-force-query-plans/#use-index-use-a-limited-set-of-indexes) exist, because you may know the data better than the engine does, and sometimes hinting against what it would normally want to do is the way to correct minor mistakes as such.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. So to sum it up. It's up to the query optimizer to create the plan it thinks to suit it most? Is there anything i can do to change that? Some variables tweak, config? Besides the index hints. Thank you again.

Comment: @MichaelGiann It depends on the query, sometimes re-writing a query alters the plan operations (actually usually it does) but for something specific like your case where a subset of the data for the same query results in a full scan instead of an index seek on a particular table, I don't think there's too much you can do. You can try [UPDATING STATISTICS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/engine-independent-table-statistics/) on the Table itself or the [individual Index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index-statistics/) as sometimes statistics are outdated, otherwise you may need to use the index hint.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the "wrong" plan; it is the "right" plan for the *different* data. To  explain:

```
BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190601'
```

That is only about 5% of the bigger dataset, but about 30% of the smaller dataset.

The Optimizer has two ways to perform ranges like that -- use an index if the range is 'very' selective, or do a table scan, tossing the rows that don't apply.

When choosing between using an index versus doing a table scan, the cutoff is computed via a "cost" formula.  But it boils down to a simple rule:  "If more than *about* 20% of the table needs to be looked at, do a table scan."

Hence, when using *that* range against *those* two datasets, the Optimizer is *likely* to pick a different query plan.

The cutoff is imprecise and is sometimes far from optimal.  To avoid that, here are two suggestions:

Adjust the query:

- For testing, shrink the BETWEEN range to be a smaller percentage of the total so that the Optimizer will be likely to pick the same query plan

And/or adjust the what you build the subset:

- Pull out a small percentage of *customers* (not *dates*) when building the 'test' dataset.
- Or a subset containing only Mondays.
- Or maybe a dataset with a fraction of dates *and* a fraction of customers.

Any of those can lead to anomalies like the one in question, so it might be better to build multiple datasets to test against -- and run tests against each.

Comment: Is there anyway to interfere or change the cost formula somehow? even if it requires some "dirty or not approved hack" on the way mariadb is meant to work so for example as you said "If more than about 20% of the table needs to be looked at, do a table scan." change the 20% to 40%

Comment: @MichaelGiann. - The 20% is not in the formula; it has been empirically derived from experience.  The real action is a "cost" formula.  It may have some obscure tunables.  The problem is none of it (to my knowledge) takes into account whether blocks are currently in cache (the buffer_pool) -- this is the dominant factor in performance.  Also, I don't think it even lets you say HDD vs SSD -- another big factor.